# Font does not change dynamically

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a Windows Form containing a `DataGridView` which binds to a `DataSet` dynamically. In the form on the `Button.Click` event I am changing the `DataGridView.Font` appearance.

I tried the below code but it's not affecting the `DataGridView`. Only the header part is being changed.

Please recommend what I've done wrong in coding.

**My Code**

```
private void Btn_Language_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(DGV_View.Font.Name == "Trebuchet MS")
    {
        DGV_View.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("NILKANTH", 12);               
        this.DGV_View.DefaultCellStyle.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("NILKANTH", 12);  
    }
    else if(DGV_View.Font.Name == "NILKANTH")
    {
        DGV_View.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Trebuchet MS", 11);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DataGridViewCellStyle style = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
style.Font = new Font(dataGridView.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
dataGridView.Rows[0].DefaultCellStyle = style;
```

Just saw it on the other site.